# AWS Mac EC2 bash command running as root assuming another user not finding binary that it should know about

Tags: bash, macos, shell, amazon-ec2, switch-user

Sorry for the mouthful title, I wasn't sure how to describe this situation in more accurate, simpler terms, suggestions welcome.

I am running a script on an AWS MacOS machine, as root user. The script at some point runs a command as another user (in this case, ec2-user), but when it does, it errors out saying the binary (in this case, brew) I am calling is not found, even though if I log in as ec2-user you can find the binary.

The script, simplified, is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - "ec2-user" -c 'brew --version'
```

Which errors out as:

```
root$ ./script.sh
zsh:1: command not found: brew
```

`root` itself does not have `brew` in it's `PATH`, however, if I switch user to `ec2-user`, brew is found:

```
root$ brew --version
-sh: brew: command not found
root$ sudo su - ec2-user
ec2-user$ brew --version
Homebrew 4.1.3
```

When I replicate this exact same issue on my personal computer (substituting only the user), even though `root` doesn't know about `brew`, it works fine:

```
personal-computer-root$ brew --version
-sh: brew: command not found
personal-computer-root$ ./script.sh
Homebrew 4.1.11
```

Even if I do add brew to the `PATH` of the `root` user, nothing changes

```
root$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
root$ ./script.sh
zsh:1: command not found: brew
```

Both Macs seem to have the same build and product version

```
$sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.5.2
BuildVersion:       22G91
```

I am completely lost as to why this is happening, and why the error is showing as `zsh` even though the shell running should be `bash` according to the shebang. If anyone has any ideas as to what could be happening, I would love to hear it.